# Connection between $k \cdot p$ equation and Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation

The Schrödinger equation for electrons in a parabolic band in the presence of slowly varying external fields is:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m^{*}}\frac{\mathrm d^2\psi}{\mathrm dx^2} + V_\mathrm{ext}\psi = E\psi \tag{1} $$

My question is: Is this the Schrödinger equation for the full wavefunction of the electrons? My confusion arises from the fact that the effective mass approximation stems from the [$\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{p}$-equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C2%B7p_perturbation_theory), which is an equation for the lattice periodic part, $u_{n,\textbf{k}}(\textbf{r})$, which is not the full wavefunction, since it is modified by a plane wave. Maybe I am mixing up different concepts in my confusion..

Comment: Where did you find equation 1, or why do you believe it's correct? And what does psi mean in that equation?